# How do i get the full name from this function constructor

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying (and failing miserably) to retrieve the full name of manTwo using a function in my function constructor. Any help would be gratefully appreciated. Ta

```
function clenk(arg1, arg2) {
this.firstName = arg1;
this.lastName  = arg2;
fullName: function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}


var manTwo = new clenk("Mike","Tool");
manTwo.fullName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
fullName: function () {
```

to

```
this.fullName = function () {
```

You could also use the prototype:

```
function clenk(arg1, arg2) {
    this.firstName = arg1;
    this.lastName  = arg2;
}
clenk.prototype.fullName = function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

which is more efficient if you create many instances of `clenk` (note that the standard practice is to use an uppercase letter for the first letter of the "class")

Comment: couldnt get the first method you suggested o work? second one worked a treat though